# In a k-map, why don't we go from 00 to 10 instead of the normal 00 01 in the sequence 00 01 11 10?

Tags: karnaugh-map

We have seen that the k map sequence follows the grey code and in a 3 variable k map, yz has the sequence 00 01 11 10
x is of the sequence 0 1.

But why does yz not follow the sequence 00 10 11 01? Is this a convention?

I tried doing it in the alternative sequence for a three variable k map and got the required answer but not so for a four variable k map. Therefore, I am not sure if it works universally.

Answer (score 0):

I learned it as 00 01 11 10, and have always seen it that way; not sure if it is a "standard".  However, 00 10 11 01 will work too--the requirement is that only one variable changes at a time.